# Public Java Swing App connect to database

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

I am developing a Java Swing app used by the public. This app requires connection a mysql database. Should I connect to the database straight from the Java Swing app?

Comment: General convention would recommend that you have a "manager" API which deals with these types of things, which controls what you can do and how the objects representing the data are created.  How you physically connect to the database will depend on where the database is stored.  If it's on a different server, a web interface/restful API might be more appropriate (not to  mention more flexible)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought about a web interface too. But wouldn't that unnecessarily slow down things, because I now have to connect via the we interface, go through additional method calls e.g. webservices, process code on server side?

Comment: It will add an overhead, but what it adds is a layer of security, as you're limiting what people can do via the web service as well as limiting the domain which can actively connect to the database (only incoming connections from your web server itself) and decoupling the code, so your client doesn't care what database is been used, only that the web service maintains it's API contract

Comment: thank you. Any links on how i can code a java web service?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how much you trust your clients. Exposing your **whole database** to external networks can be risky, because a malicious user could easily reverse engineer your program to find out the credentials to connect to your database. While you could defend to some extent from the risks associated with this by pushing down security to the database, a proper service layer written in a general purpose programming language like Java would be much more suitable for this. And with a proper service API to access your database you could make much higher guarantees for data consistency in your database. Later, you could even switch between database vendors or even switch to another storage method like a NoSQL solution, while keeping the Swing client practically unchanged (given a properly designed service API). On the long run, it would be definitely worth the effort.

**EDIT**: follow up answer on how to implement such a web service

If you want to minimize external dependencies, you could go with a solution based purely on Java standards, like [JAX-WS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_XML_Web_Services). It's available as part of the [JavaEE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition) platform, so, while not strictly necessary, it's probably a good idea to use a compliant implementation, as it provides services like declarative transactions, authentication and authorization, and many more things that you might need while implementing and exposing your service API. [Spring Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework) is a popular alternative for JavaEE if you want total control over your backend service layer, but it would probably take much more up-front investment in terms of learning curve. You can connect to either JAX-WS services or [Spring Remoting](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html) from Java SE apps, so both can be a viable path to achieve a proper [3-tiered architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture).

Comment: Thank you. I am not an expert programmer, so pardon my stupid comments if any. =)
So, for a Java Swing app, how should I develop a web service layer in Java?

Comment: I've edited my answer to follow-up on your question. Perfectly good question, btw. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I know if there is any host that you recommend that I can run my server side java code?

Comment: You mean a [Platform as a Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_as_a_service) provider that can run Java technologies?